# Greeting based on local time not server time

Tags: php, date, time, timezone, localtime

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
$time = time();
$hour = date("G",$time);
echo $hour;

    if(($hour >= 0) && ($hour <=3)) {
        $greeting == 'Good Evening';
    }
    elseif(($hour >= 4) && ($hour <=11)) {
        $greeting == 'Good Morning';
    }
    elseif(($hour >= 12) && ($hour <=18)){
        $greeting == 'Good Afternoon';
    }
    elseif(($hour >= 19) && ($hour <= 24)) {
        $greeting == 'Good Evening';
    }
echo $greeting;
```

First, I prefilled "America/Chicago", I would like this to be automatically detected based on current user's local time not UTC.

Second, as you can see, I echoed $hour, as a test, to see what was displaying.  At the time I did this, $hour was 8.  But, my if statements were never "true", therefore, no greeting was outputted, At the time, 8, should have displayed Good Morning as the greeting.  I am positive I'm probably making some silly mistake, but I've been working with this code for three hours.  Please help!  Thank You!

Comment: Looks like your using a comparison operator instead of an assignment operator for '$greeting'

Comment: `$greeting ==` remove one of the equal signs for all of those and try again. If that fixed it, you can just delete the question.

Comment: How can you use an assignment operator instead?  The comparison operator is doing just that, comparing.  Comparing time, in order to say if this time equals (or is greater than) this time, then (condition) display this greeting?

Comment: the syntax is `$greeting =` to assign, not `$greeting ==`

Comment: I really need to learn how to take a break.  I've been overworking my brain I didn't catch that.

Comment: believe me, it happens to everyone.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the user's local timezone?  I've found a lot of very complex methods.  And I need it in a php variable, rather than javascript if possible.  Thank You!

Comment: question first: by changing those to single equal signs; did it not solve your original question?

Comment: If you post it as an answer, I'll gladly give it a vote!

Comment: you're welcome. Well, if you want to get the user's current time, you will need to use a JS method, since servers work on their current timezone and not the users themselves.

Comment: No need to answer, there was already a duplicate question for it that I closed the question with. Thanks anyways though ;-)

Comment: ok, I don't mind using javascript if needed.  I just want to set the default to their actual time.

Comment: Here, see this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript - You can further your research using these keywords "get user's timezone javascript".

Comment: This is why I don't like working with javascript.  Now, I have a number I can't do anything with.  Say for example, I have `-300`, UTC+5 - how do I insert this into `date_default_timezone_set();`?

Comment: I appreciate the reference to that answer, but... it just gives you a useless value, doesn't actually set the timezone.

Comment: In your opinion, is it more reliable to have the user choose his/her own timezone?  That's something I can easily make happen.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22625076/634824) for getting the time zone.